# How do I render an orthographic image of a 20km x 20km mesh in 2.8?

Tags: rendering, camera

I have a 20k x 20k mesh.
Output is set to 25000px x 25000px, BW, PNG
Camera is set to Orthographic, Location, x=0, y=0, z=25216.7m

For some reason when I press 0 on the numpad for the camera view, it looks like the camera is about 0.5m from the ground. The camera is certainly at about 25000 from a visual estimate. Can anyone please give me suggestions on what I'm missing. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In ortho mode it doesn't count how far is your camera from the object. You have to adjust the Orthographic Scale in the camera settings.

Comment: I changed my Orthographic scale to 20000.0 and that worked perfectly. Thanks FFeller.